# Get Identity of my Service Application

Tags: powershell

I have written following powershell code

```
$list = Get-SPServiceApplication | ?{$_.DisplayName -eq "AmOwaWordSvcApp"} 
| %{$_.ServiceInstances} | ?{$_.Status -eq "Online"}
```

For these 2 online  isntances of my service application... is it possible to know under which windows identity  are these two running?

I did $list[0] | Get-Member but I am not getting anything which gives me the identity name which is running this instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SPServiceApplication you get if you omit your last line has a property ApplicationPool which has a property ProcessAccount